# dual boot windows 7 with xp hard drive compatibility mode

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, hard-drive, multi-boot

I need to get a Compaq 620 laptop with Windows 7 to dual boot with Windows xp
I tried running the Windows XP setup CD, but soon after I get a BSOD error
[This page says](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-118712-blue-screen-while-trying-to-install-xp) that I need to change the hard drive compatibility to IDE from AHCI
Will changing hard drive compatibility affect my current Windows 7 installation in any way?
I need Windows XP to run some software I cannot run otherwise, but I don't want to jeopardize my working Windows 7 installation in any way, so I want to confirm everything before I proceed with this

Comment: If you're running Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise, or Ultimate why not just use Windows XP Mode? - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-xp-mode

Comment: I don't want anything that I install in the XP system to effect the Windows 7 system in any way, so it's better to make a dual boot

Comment: and I am having issues with running it in vmware

Comment: @user13267 - Be specific what are your issues?

Comment: If I ]increase the resolution of the virtual XP the vmware window gets horizontal and vertical scroll bars instead of the whole thing fitting in one big window. Also it seems a bit slow. It's better for me if I can get a dual system to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching your drive to IDE from AHCI will not render your Windows 7 install unusable. You will have to reboot it once on your first time booting into Windows 7 tho, as it will update the hard drive controller driver.

One alternative would be to use something like VirtualBox, which is free and would allow you to visualize Windows XP while still being in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 supports both AHCI and IDE mode, but IDE mode will be slower, some features might not be available, and you might run into issues due to the wrong drivers being loaded.

Is there some specific reason you'll have to run Windows XP natively/without a VM?

I'd recommend you try some virtualization software, such as [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/). This allows you to run most operating systems at almost full speed (depending on your actual hardware). Especially Windows guests profit off many features, such as full support for hardware accelerated 2D/3D.

It's not necessarily perfect for gaming, but you shouldn't run into any issues running any kind of other desktop software (and even games with lower hardware requirements).

In general, this provides you with quite a few interesting benefits:

- You're able to use your Windows XP programs in tandem with anything running under Windows 7 (direct interaction like copying things through the clipboard or drag&droping files works (limited)).
- You don't have to worry about breaking your MBR, boot manager, or anything else.
- You can reset/revert the virtual machine at any time or uninstall everything like any other program.